# Issue with changing ActionBar background - Android

Tags: android

Hey guys I am newer to Android development and I am working on changing my ActionBar's background.  When adding the following in my `themes.xml` file within `res->values`

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item> 
</style>
```

I receive this error message:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/
 actionbar_background').
```

I am not positive why I am receiving this message and could use a hand.

David

Comment: try using <item name="android:backgroundStacked">hex_color_or_drawable</item>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just guessing, but my bet is that you don't have any drawable named `actionbar_background.png`

Double check for possible typos in your png resource. It should be in any `drawable` folder. Or you could just set a color with.-

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
   <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item> 
</style>
```

---

Please notice that hardcoding values is a bad practice. If you finally go for a background color, you should consider creating a resource item for that color, in a separate resource file (i.e. colors.xml)

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

And reference it with in your item style with `@color/red`

Comment: Wait ohhhh, where would I put the image actionbar_background.png, or how could I give it a color>

Comment: what would be hardcoding it into the code such as the awnser above said?

Comment: I meant that I put in the first code snippet `#FF0000` directly into the item. The right way is define the color resource like in the second snippet, and 'insert' its value with `@color/red`

Comment: Okay so I changed it to what you suggested, is this better practice than telling it straight in the java file?  Or is it better to use XML files to do all that?

Comment: Yes, every time you can, remember to define a resource apart, not just for colors, but for strings, integers and dimensions as well, as it will be a lot easier to maintain and change those values.

Comment: so inside I would call the color with: `<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
         <item name="android:background">@colors/red</item> 
    </style> ` but in my colors.xml file I would have the following: `<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>`

Comment: Exactly, but it would be @color/red (not @colors/red).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38304/discussion-between-david-biga-and-ssantos)

Answer (score 5):

You can use it when activity created. (onCreate)

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
//for color
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00C4CD")));
//for image
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_icon));
```

Comment: Why do I need to specify the getActionBar()?

Comment: how can you edit it without specify ? That isn't for the custom actionbar, That's for editing existed actionbar.

Comment: Is it better to do that way or no?

Comment: If you want to change small part of action bar like just color or background image, this is the better way.

Comment: But lets say in general when you want to contain all your styles and what not for an application, is it better to do so? Also for importing an image where would you place the image to load it, and where would you reference the image?

Comment: As I said, If you want to change small things, you should use java. Because XML requires more effort. You can keep those images in main drawable folder. If you want to more complicated design for action bar, you should use xml. Doing by using java is the easy way.

Comment: The XML solution given above this answer didnt work for me. But this piece of code worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a reference file in drawable folder. you will find the folder under res just put an image file under drawable named as actionbar_background and the error should be resolved. you can download the image just google actionbar_background. hope it helps